# Set default home page via <welcome-file> in JSF project

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, homescreen, welcome-file

I am unable to set a default page that loads in the browser when I start a Java EE project using Tomcat 8.0 from Eclipse.
I am trying to learn JSF, so I followed [this tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Ftutorial%2FJSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html)

Everything works fine, but I can only see the created pages when I right click on the `login.xhtml` or `welcome.xhtml` file and choose "Run As/Run on Server".

So far, all the other web applications I have created loaded default page when I started the entire project. The default behavior is to load `index.html` page (or maybe index.jsp if there is some). So I added `index.html` and `index.xhtml` pages into my `WEB-INF` folder in the project, hoping that at least one of them will be shown. However, nothing happens. The browser always shows just the page on `localhost:8080/JSFFaceletsTutorial/` URL, but the page is white clean, not even an error message. I think I have been getting error 404 in the process of solving this issue along the way, however, I am no longer able to reproduce this error and I don't remember what caused it.

I found that it's possible to [change the default starting page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F)

However, it doesn't work for me either. Regardless if I edit the `web.xml` file or not, I am getting the same result.

What is even more puzzling, is that when I tried to change the web browser: "Window/Web Browser/..." it acted for a while differently in the external web browsers than in the internal Eclipse web browser. The internal had always blank page - but the external web browsers once managed to show the `index.html` page - but it was some outdated version. Despite I made absolutely sure that I edited it, saved the changes, restarted the server... and still, it showed me the outdated version of the page.
And even in this case, it still ignored the changes made in the `web.xml` file.
But when I am trying it now, it again shows blank white page in all browsers. I am not aware of any change I made except for editing `web.xml` file...

My guess is that the problem is in the JSF technology I don't fully grasp yet. It's because when I choose to run the `login.xhtml` and `welcome.xhtml` pages using right click "Run As/Run on Server", the URL of those pages are on `localhost:8080:` with path `/JSFFaceletsTutorial/faces/login.xhtml` and `/JSFFaceletsTutorial/faces/welcome.xhtml`. That is weird, because I don't have any directory "faces" in my project.
Typing all possible permutations of:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

in the `web.xml` didn't help either. It didn't help when I typed the full address there either.

Here are warnings I am getting in the console (I skipped the INFO log entries):

> "Dec 19, 2014 9:39:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>   WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFFaceletsTutorial' did not find a matching property.
>   ...
>   WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named 'loginBean' has already been registered.  Replacing existing managed bean class type com.tutorial.LoginBean with com.tutorial.LoginBean.
>   Dec 19, 2014 9:39:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start"

I am not sure this is helpful though.
I am out of ideas now.

Comment: I think its just <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>?  All your files are named .xhtml? so that would be the first guess. Note if you use a servlet mapping for the JSF servlet (*.jsf) to point to .xhtml files the welcome file will not be able to pick it up. It needs to be a physical file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the `<welcome-file>` does not represent the path to the "default home page". It represents the filename of the physical file contained in the folder which you'd like to serve up as default file when a **folder** like `/`, `/foo/`, `/foo/bar/`, etc is requested.

So, in JSF 2.x flavor, that would basically be:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This way, if the enduser requests `/` and you have `/index.xhtml`, then it will be served. Or, if the enduser requests `/foo` and you have `/foo/index.xhtml`, then it will be served, etc. If there is no such file, then a 404 error will be returned.

Now, you appear to have mapped your `FacesServlet` on a prefix `<url-pattern>` of `/faces/*`. This is a leftover from JSF 1.0/1.1 ages and really not recommended these days. Perhaps you were reading an outdated tutorial targeted at JSF 1.x, or a poorly maintained tutorial which was originally written for JSF 1.x and then uncarefully updated for JSF 2.x instead of rewritten from scratch.

That tutorial did also not seem to have explained you [some servlet basics](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Namely, in order to get JSF components in the XHTML page to run and generate some HTML output, the `FacesServlet` has to be invoked when the XHTML page is being requested. When you request the XHTML page like so `/index.xhtml`, while the `FacesServlet` is being mapped on `/faces/*`, then it won't be invoked. The browser would then retrieve the raw unparsed JSF source code instead of the generated HTML output. You can see it by rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser. You should have requested the page like so `/faces/index.xhtml` so that the `FacesServlet` can run and produce HTML output which the browser can understand and present.

That only doesn't go well together with welcome files. This totally explains why you get a "clean white" (blank) page when using `index.xhtml` as welcome file (some inferior webbrowsers like IE would confusingly [prompt a download dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721996/) because of missing/wrong content type on the response containing raw XHTML source code). The `FacesServlet` was simply not being invoked. Just get rid of the old fashioned `/faces/*` URL pattern and use the JSF 2.x minded `*.xhtml` URL pattern instead.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way the welcome files should work and you can just open JSF pages by directly requesting its physical URL without hassling with virtual URLs. This was not possible in JSF 1.x because it would let the `FacesServlet` run in an infinite loop calling itself and cause a stack overflow.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/)
- [Setting application URL on WAS server, where does /faces/ come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265953/setting-application-url-on-was-server-where-does-faces-come-from/)
- [What is the difference between creating JSF pages with .jsp or .xhtml or .jsf extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-jsf-pages-with-jsp-or-xhtml-or-jsf-ex)
- [Why can web.xml welcome-file be located inside WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821984/why-can-web-xml-welcome-file-be-located-inside-web-inf/)
- [How to use a sub-folder as web.xml welcome directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425010/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-as-web-xml-welcome-directory/)

---

As to those warnings, they are **unrelated** but quite googlable.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that it represents only physical file. I just didn't explain it right. I was not trying to run those pages login.xhtml and welcome.xhtml on default. I was trying to create a new page with a link to this login page. That new page would be just a new simple physical file.
I knew about servlets, I was working on jsp pages few years back. Though thanks for the third link especially. It will come in handy.
It works now, it was problem with the servlet-mapping tag. Interesting that this was not allowed in JSF 1...

Comment: @BalusC        I'm fiddling with this issue at the moment. I want to have custom mapping so I replaced `/faces/*` with `*.html`. However, my index page is behaving unexpected. I tried `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>` but it only displays my title in the upper left corner (I'm using template, with `<ui:composition>`. When I inspect the source code, it shows the source code of the index file itself. If I put the `x`html back, both for welcome file and the mapping, it works again. So, it seems that they need to be in sync. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default page in the web.xml file to have the facesServlet invoked in JSF in 2 ways:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

or invoke the facesServlet directly from the welcome file like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
 version="4.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.xyz.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/main/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
<!--         <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.xyz.servlets.login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->

</web-app>
```