# Use of welcome-file-list, why can we specify a list if it would run only one?

Tags: servlets, welcome-file

In my JSF application welcome file is set to `index.xhtml`.

My doubt is, when more than one welcome file is given, which one is run?

If only the first welcome file runs, why do we have `<welcome-file-list>` which allows multiple welcome files?

Answer (score 1):

Because a "welcome file" is not a "homepage file" as many starters misinterpret them. A "welcome file" is the default file which should be served up when **any folder** is requested. This not only includes the root ("home page") folder `http://example.com/context/`, but also all subfolders like `http://example.com/context/foo/`, `http://example.com/context/foo/bar/`, etc.

Those subfolders may have differently named "startup" files. That's exactly why you can specify multiple of them.

Do note that this is not JSF specific. The `web.xml` is part of Servlet API, not JSF API.

#### See also:

- [Set default home page via <welcome-file> in JSF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562813/set-default-home-page-via-welcome-file-in-jsf-project/)