# Is it possible to prevent redirecting / to /welcome-file when using OmniFaces ExtensionlessURLs

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm using JSF 2.2 and OmniFaces [ExtensionlessURLs](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) to remove the file extensions from my URLs: 
`www.exmaple.com/appname/login.xhtml -> .../appname/login`.
Now when I navigate to `www.example.com/appname/` I always get forwarded to `www.exmaple.com/appname/login`. Is it possible to prevent this redirect and to instead serve `login.xhtml` from `www.example.com/appname/`?

My .xhtml-files are stored in `/WebContent/html/`.

Relevant details from my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
   <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
   <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
   <param-value>/html/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs):

> ### Advanced configuration
>
> See [package documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.2/org/omnifaces/facesviews/package-summary.html) for configuration settings as to mapping, filtering and forwarding behavior.

From the [package documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.2/org/omnifaces/facesviews/package-summary.html):

> #### Welcome files
>
> If a `<welcome-file>` is defined in `web.xml` that's scanned by FacesViews **AND** `REDIRECT_TO_EXTENSIONLESS` is used (which is the default, see below), it's necessary to define an extensionless welcome file to prevent a request to `/` being redirected to `/[welcome file]`. E.g. without this `http://example.com` will redirect to say `http://example.com/index`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <welcome-file-list>
>     <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
> </welcome-file-list>
> ```

In other words, edit your welcome file to say `login` instead of `login.xhtml`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: note though that you seem to have a general misunderstanding of the exact meaning of a "welcome file", because it's a bit strange that you could possibly have a `login.xhtml` file in every single folder. See also [Set default home page via <welcome-file> in JSF project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27562813/)